# Get Data from JSON Python?

Tags: python, json, string

I'm working on doing a live currency converter in Python. I've successfully fetched all the data needed from the URL into Python. However I'm now trying to call a specific string in the url. Here's my current code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

##Define JSON API Url
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=XXX") as url:
    response = url.read()

##Print Fetched data
print (response)
```

As you can see I've printed all the data it's fetched, but it's now printing specific strings from it.

My question is, how do i parse specific strings from the url ? I've heard of json.load ,is that something i should use ?

Comment: what's the question? did you try `json.loads(response)`?

Comment: Sorry my question has been edited. Could you explain further with the json.loads ? Thank you for the fast reply

Comment: better to search documentation first: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: Your question would have started out better had you just tried `json.loads()` *first*. You may have run into problems, but you could then at least have included the error message here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to load the data as JSON; the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) can do this for you, but you need to decode the data to text first.

```
import urllib.request
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=XXX") as url:
    response = url.read()

charset = url.info(). get_content_charset('utf-8')  # UTF-8 is the JSON default
data = json.loads(response.decode(charset))
```

From there on out `data` is a Python object.

Judging by the [documenation](https://openexchangerates.org/documentation#preview-api-response) you should be able to access rates as:

```
print('Euro rate', data['rates']['EUR'])
```

for example.